# Understanding shutdown mode in STM32L47

Tags: power-supply, stm32, low-power

I am using an STM32L476 for my application and want to use shutdown mode to conserve the battery life of the device.

I was going through the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0351-stm32l47xxx-stm32l48xxx-stm32l49xxx-and-stm32l4axxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) and found the following:

> Shutdown mode: VCORE domain is powered off. All clocks in the VCORE domain are stopped, the PLL, the MSI, the HSI16, the LSI and the HSE are disabled. The LSE can be kept running. The system clock, when exiting the Shutdown mode, is MSI at 4 MHz. In this mode, the supply voltage monitoring is disabled and the product behavior is not guaranteed in case of a power voltage drop.

I have the following questions:

1. What does *product behavior is not guaranteed in case of a power voltage drop* mean?
2. I have a battery operated device (battery voltage 4.2 - 2.7 V), an LDO supplies a constant 3.3 V. I have a cutoff voltage of 3.3 V; after 3.3 V no supply will be given to the controller.

Will I be able to use shutdown mode for my application? Or do I need to use some other mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It means that the MCU cannot detect an undervoltage condition and reset itself if the supply voltage drops below the minimum operating voltage, but does not go low enough to be considered to be fully powered off, the internal state of any circuit in the MCU can't be guaranteed and it may not wake up from shutdown mode.
2. If the supply does not dip below minimum MCU operating voltage while the MCU is in shutdown mode then that is fine.

Comment: *It may not wake up from shutdown mode*. I didn't understand this part fully. If MCU never wakes up in-case of undervoltage, will the application I am working on become useless and the only option left is to reprogram it?

Comment: No, that is not what it means. In case of undervoltage event happened during shutdown, the MCU just needs a reset pulse or valid powerdown-powerup event.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I have only one push button which wakes up the device through GPIO interrupt so reset pulse wont be possible. Can you please brief about valid power-down power-up event?

Comment: I am sure the datasheet for your specific MCU model will be a better source for that. But you say that below 3.3V the MCU won't get any power so isn't that enough? And if you have a battery and LDO, what would cause a undervoltage event during shutdown mode? How likely would such an event be?

Comment: Right, LDO should work and under voltage event shouldn't ideally occur. Thank you for your inputs.